# How can I distinguish between two files with the same name in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I've got two index.html files for different subdomains (www. and gametimer.smartersoftware.de). I have enabled sub-domain tracking in Google Analytics and posted the corresponding script.

However, I only see index.html, apparently for both files. I would like to be able to distinguish between the two. What do I have to change to enable that?

Comment: Are the page titles different? You can view the analytics by page title if they are to differentiate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, if the page titles are different, would be to view the analytics by 'page title' instead of by 'page'.

Answer (score 1):

Well you should be able to tell what ones are different from hovering over them, personally I'd remove `index.html` all together and just have / as the root.

You can remove `index.html` so it appears as `domainname.com/` by editing the htaccess file.

Add the below code if this solution works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On # remove this, if you have it already

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Alternatively you could make visitors go to `/site1.html` and `/site2.html` using the redirect in the htaccess but to be honest for the sake of Analytics its rather silly since your adding a redirect on a site which some people don't like and it adds some render time on the page.

Comment: Maybe my question was a bit muddy: I'm seeing only one index.html in the list - showing the sum of both files. I'm not sure how rewriting the URLs is going to change that.